# Fast way to write itemize list

Tags: beamer, itemize, markdown

I'm using `beamer` to make presentation slides. In `beamer`, a lot of `itemize` lists are usually used.

Is there some quick way to write an `itemize` list like Markdown?

When some list such as below is needed:

- aa
- bb
- cc

In LaTeX:

```
  \begin{itemize}
  \item
  aa
  \item
  bb
  \item
  cc
  \end{itemize}
```

In Markdown, you can just write:

```
+ aa
+ bb
+ cc
```

Markdown is much easier and quicker. How can I use a Markdown-style way of achieving the same output in `beamer`?

Comment: You could probably write the lists in markdown and convert them to .tex with [pandoc](http://pandoc.org/index.html).

Comment: Welcome! There's no reason, as @Null says, that you can't convert them from markdown.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Without using `pandoc`, the `outlines` package is a good option to type simple or nested list:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{outlines}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Minimal working example}{Outline lists}
\begin{outline}
\1 First level
\1 First level again 
\2 Second level again
\3 Third level 
\3 Third level agaim
\end{outline}
Note that the 4th level is not allowed in Beamer
\begin{outline}[enumerate]
\1 First level
\2 Second level 
\1 First level again 
\2 Second level again
\3 Third level 
\3 Third level agaim
\0 Some normal text whitin outline environment. \par
\1 Another list
\end{outline}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can write the list in Markdown and convert it to LaTeX using [pandoc](http://pandoc.org/index.html). The tool's website includes some [demos](http://pandoc.org/demos.html) which include examples of converting from Markdown to LaTeX. For example, one demo shows the conversion of this text:

```
% Eating Habits
% John Doe
% March 22, 2005

# In the morning

- Eat eggs
- Drink coffee

# In the evening

- Eat spaghetti
- Drink wine

# Conclusion

- And the answer is...
- $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(x-a)^n$
```

to `beamer` slides:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

using the command

```
pandoc -t beamer SLIDES -o example8.pdf
```

Comment: The bottom half of the sum sign in the last slide is missing.

Comment: @hkBst For some reason it displays like that using my browser's internal PDF viewer. Good catch -- it's fixed now.